# MS ACCESS SQL Query two tables getting varius data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL and am having trouble setting up this query. I have two tables, one which holds info about the teams, named TEAMS which looks like this:

**TEAMS**

```
Name|City|Attendance
Jets|  NY| 50
...
```

And the other which holds info about the games played, named GAMES:

**GAMES**

```
Home|Visitors|Date     |Result
Jets| Broncos| 1/1/2012| Tie
...
```

For this specific query I need to find each team that had one or more home games, give the name of the team, the number of wins, the number of losses, and the number of ties. I'm having trouble figuring out how to combine the data, I have made several queries that individually find the amount of losses, wins and ties but I don't know how to join properly or that even is the right approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you pretty close but without understanding your data fully I can't really give you a perfect working query, but at least you can see what the join might look like.

```
SELECT TeamName, SUM(SWITCH(Result = 'Win', 1)) AS Wins, SUM(SWITCH(Result = 'Tie', 1)) AS Ties, SUM(SWITCH(Result = 'Loss', 1)) AS Loss 
FROM Teams INNER JOIN Games ON (Teams.TeamName = Games.Home OR Teams.TeamName = Games.Visitors)
GROUP BY TeamName
HAVING MAX(SWITCH(Teams.TeamName = Games.Home, 1)) = 1;
```

It'd be better database design to have IDs instead of team names in the games table, and also having a description like "Tie", "Win", "Loss" I wasn't sure which team that'd refer to (obviously tie is easy), so right now the query just takes whatever is in that column, which I'm sure is incorrect, but it should be a small change to fix it.